# What is the fastest way to run a single function thousands of times with a different set of parameters on each run?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am working on a custom grid search function in order to find the best set of hyperparameters. I am not using GridSearchCV due to certain limitations of my program so I am having to implement it on my own.

The structure of my grid search is as follows:

```
def get_search_space():
  """ function to get a list of lists of all possible combinations of 
       hyperaparmeters """

  return inputs
```

each list in inputs will contain following parameters: train_size, name_of_model, num_of_hidden_layers, normalized

example of this can be the following:
`[0.8, "longformer", 4, True]`

and to reiterate, there will be a larger list of thousands of such lists with different combinations of hyperparameters

```
def search_best_parameters(dataset, name_of_model, num_of_hidden_layers, normalized):

   """ code to apply parameter set on dataset, will return accuracy"""

   return accuracy


if "__name__" == "__main__":
    for dataset in datasets:
       inputs = get_search_space()
       name_of_model, num_of_hidden_layers, normalized = inputs
       search_best_parameters(dataset, name_of_model, num_of_hidden_layers, normalized)
```

I have been playing around with multiprocessing library but I have had no real luck with it so far. I am also using cuda gpu on colab to run my model which has also been a challenge as I got an error with multiprocessing that said "Cannot re-initalize CUDA in forked subprocess". I also want to store the accuracy as well as the set of hyperparameters in a data structure such a dictionary at the end as well. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure it this solves your problem, but you can use gridsearchcv and set the jobs to -1.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply! I cannot use GridSearchCV due to some limitations of my program which is why I had to implement grid search myself

Comment: how long does testing 1 set of hyperparameters take? order of magnitude accuracy 1 μs, 1 ms, 1 s, 1 minute?

Comment: it can take up to a 1-1.5 minutes. These are large transformer models so it takes some time.

Comment: Per your code, for each dataset you are calling `inputs = get_search_space()`. If the return list of lists never varies for each dataset, then this line should be moved before the loop. How large is `datasets`? I am also not clear on what your output is. For a given dataset are we looking for the element of `inputs` (i.e. hyperparameters) that returns maximum accuracy?